# What does it mean to satisfy O(f(N)) for a given equation f(N)?

Tags: c++, big-o

This is the only question on my final review that I'm still uncertain about. I've figured all of the other 74 out, but this one is completely stumping me. I think it has something to do with finding C and k, but I don't remember how to do this or what it even means... and I may not even be on the right track there.

The question I'm encountering is "What is the minimum acceptable value for N such that the definition for `O(f(N))` is satisfied for member function `Heap::Insert(int v)`?"

The code for Heap::Insert(int v) is as follows:

```
void Insert(int v) 
{ 
  if (IsFull()) return; 
  int p=++count; 

  while (H[p/2] > v) { 
     H[p] = H[p/2]; 
     p/= 2; 
  } 
  H[p] = v; 
}
```

The possible answers given are: `32, 64, 128, 256`.

I'm completely stumped and have to take this exam in the morning. Help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is a heap insert? I see an infinite loop in the `while` statement.

Comment: This is bad code, it is not bounded by any real valued function. But for the sake of argument, what's the definition of f?

Answer (score 1):

I admit the question is quite obscure, but I will try to give a reasonable explanation.

If we call `f(N)` the temporal complexity of the operation executed by your code as a function of the number of elements in the heap, the professor wanted you to remember that `f(N) = O(log(N))` for a binary heap insert, that is `O(h)`, where `h` is the height of the heap and we assume it to be complete (remember how a heap works and that it can be represented as a binary tree). Thus, you have to try those four values of `Nmin` and find the smallest one that satisfies the definition, i.e. the one for which

```
f(n) <= k*log(N)
```

For each `N >= Nmin` and at least a  `k`. I would give you the details for calculating `f(N)` if only your code did what the professor or you expected it to do.

Note: I'd really love a LaTeX render over Stack Overflow questions! Like on Math

Comment: The problem is that if `f` is any function from the reals to the positive reals such that `Insert` has asymptotic complexity `O(f(n))`, then there exists a `k` satisfying that inequality for *any* finite `Nmin`. I took the question to mean f was from the reals to the functions on the reals, but I think your interpretation is more likely.

Comment: Stefano, thanks for answering. I think you got me on the right track here, but now, I have no idea what `k` is or how to find it. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Actually you don't have to find it, just choose one (appropriately)